# Interpretation of Gaussian of a matrix

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, matrix

What analogies and differences exists between the Gaussian function on the reals $e^{-x^2}$ and the matrix Gaussian $\exp(-X^2)$ where $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and $X$ is an $n\times n$ matrix? Here $\exp$ is the [matrix exponential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_exponential).

Is there a way to renormalize the matrix Gaussian so as to give it some sort of probabilistic/statistical interpretation? Is there a matrix version of mean and variance that makes sense here?

Comment: How do you define $\exp(-X^2)$? Do you mean $\exp(-\text{Tr}(X^2))$? [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_normal_distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_normal_distribution)

Comment: The exponential function is defined for all matrices as $\exp(X)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{X^k}{k!}$. This converges everywhere and is detailed in the following link (which I'll add to the main question as well): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_exponential

Comment: Hadn't heard of the matrix normal distribution though, so thanks for sharing!

Comment: You might find it instructive to consider the case of diagonalizable $X$; that is, of the form $X=P^{-1}DP$ for diagonal $D$. In that case $$\exp(-X^2)=\exp(-P^{-1}DPP^{-1}DP)=\exp(-P^{-1}D^2P)=P^{-1}\exp(-D^2)P$$ and $\exp(-D^2)$ is a product of independent Gaussians on the coordinates.